# $.ajax call doesnt work with dataType:'json'

Tags: php, ajax

Please excuse me if this sounds stupid but I have been at it for quite some time now and cant figure out the problem.

so what   I am trying to do is :

--Make a ajax call to a php script that queries mongodb collection for some documents

-- This ajax calls gets a json back and renders it on browser.

The problem  I am having is at the first step itself.

here's my **ajax** call :

```
        $.ajax({
                type :'get',
                url: "get_data.php",
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }

            });
```

here's the php code:

```
        $n =  new MongoClient();    
        $dbname = "wsd";    
        $db = $n->$dbname; //get the collections.. 
        $collection = $db->raretweets; 
        $cursor = $collection->find();
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($cursor);
```

I suspected the problem might be with the $cursor object , So I tried the following basic stuff

```
         $data = 3;
         header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
        /* Return JSON */
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Even this gives me an error **"No element found"** in console logs of firebug.
I was wondering if anybody can hint me about the problem.

Comment: what does response show in the console?

Comment: "No element found" sounds unrelated to the Ajax part of the JavaScript.

Comment: Look at the net tab of the developer tools. Can you see the request for `get_data.php`? Can you see the response? Do they have the content you expect?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña  thanks for the reply, I dont see anything in response I can see the request going to get_data.php but its cancelled and there's nothing in response to it.

Comment: @Quentin thanks , see my comment above.

Comment: Are you loading a new page at the same time as you make the request? How are you trigging the call to `$.ajax`? Is it an event handler on a link or something?

Comment: @Quentin yeah  I load a new page the same time this request is made , it's a response to onclick event on a link,

Comment: @Riddle — That's the problem then. You are killing the execution environment for the script before you get a response.

Comment: @Quentin No I mean , this scripts executes when I visit the page So before displaying any HTML I should see a alert I coded in success callback right?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, so it won't block the rest of the page loading.

Comment: @Quentin Also , I just noticed when I change the dataType to be html I just get the whole php file in the data back .. so execution environment cannot be the problem I am guessing,

Comment: @Riddle isn't the datatype of json_encode() should be array right?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña dataType is the type of response object that'll be json.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try something really basic, something like this:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
  if(data!='Error') {
    alert(data);
  }
```

And in PHP

```
$data = 3;
if($data) {
  echo number_format($data);
} else {
  die('Error');
}
```

Does this give you a result?

Comment: hey even this gives the same "No element  found" console log. nothing in the response to the request.

Comment: This was a bit too big to put as a comment. Take a look at this: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13450